# Divide a collection into bulks and invoke a closure on each bulk in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I wonder there might be a built-in feature in Groovy, something like

```
aCollection.doEachBulk(100) { bulk -> 
    ...
}
```

Is there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you may be looking for the [`collate`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate%28int%29) method.

```
(1..20).collate(5).each { subRange ->
    println subRange
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```